# Passing value of a variable to event function

Tags: javascript, variables, events, arguments

I have some javascript that creates some buttons with click events to a function which passes the identifier for that button.  The identifier is a variable in the code that creates them.  However, the variable is being passed by reference so the value picked up by the function is the variable's last set value, not the value at the time the button was created.

This would appear to be a very simple and common pilot error, but I have not been able to find any and answer on here or the wider web.

In the example below, I'm wanting ClickedID in the Buttonclicked function to be the value of ButtonID in the CreateButtons function at the time the button was created (and shows in the button's caption), not what ButtonID was when the function completed.

```js
function CreateButtons() {
  var Buttons = document.getElementById("Buttons");
  var Button = null;
  var ButtonID = 0;

  for (ButtonID = 0; ButtonID < 6; ButtonID++) {
    Button = document.createElement("button");
    Button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Button " + ButtonID));
    Button.onclick = function() {ButtonClicked(ButtonID);};
    Buttons.appendChild(Button); }
}

function ButtonClicked (ClickedID) {
  alert("You clicked button " + ClickedID);
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
```

```html
<button onclick="CreateButtons();">Create Buttons</button>
<div id="Buttons"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `let` instead of `var` to solve this issue:

```
for (let ButtonID = 0; ButtonID < 6; ButtonID++)
```

instead of

```
var ButtonID = 0;
```

You can find docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

`let` creates block-scoped variable (so attached to `for` loop), while `var` creates a function-scoped variable (which is attached to the `CreateButton` function).

In case of `var` when `onclick` is called `ButtonID` is 6 because the loop has finished. In case of `let` each value of `ButtonID` within a loop is kept and is accessible to `onclick` handler function.

This use-case is explained in detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#creating_closures_in_loops_a_common_mistake). It contains both solutions - using `let` and IIFE (as posted by decpk)

```js
function CreateButtons() {
  var Buttons = document.getElementById("Buttons");
  var Button = null;

  for (let ButtonID = 0; ButtonID < 6; ButtonID++) {
    Button = document.createElement("button");
    Button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Button " + ButtonID));
    Button.onclick = function() {ButtonClicked(ButtonID);};
    Buttons.appendChild(Button); }
}

function ButtonClicked (ClickedID) {
  alert("You clicked button " + ClickedID);
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
```

```html
<button onclick="CreateButtons();">Create Buttons</button>
<div id="Buttons"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

### <= ES5

You can easily achieve this using [IIFE(Immediately-invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

You are getting the `buttonID` up to which the loop ends i.e `6`. What you can do is create an `IIFE` so that each iteration create a new `scope` and new `ButtonID`.

```js
function CreateButtons() {
  var Buttons = document.getElementById("Buttons");
  var Button = null;
  let ButtonID = 0;

  for (ButtonID = 0; ButtonID < 6; ButtonID++) {
    (function(btnId) {                // change
      Button = document.createElement("button");
      Button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Button " + btnId));
      Button.onclick = function() {
        ButtonClicked(btnId);
      };
      Buttons.appendChild(Button);
    })(ButtonID);                    // change
  }
}

function ButtonClicked(ClickedID) {
  alert("You clicked button " + ClickedID);
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="CreateButtons();">Create Buttons</button>
<div id="Buttons"></div>
```

### From ES6 ## - using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). Let and const declares a blocked scoped local variable

Just create a new local scope variable as follows

```
for (let ButtonID = 0; ButtonID < 6; ButtonID++) {
```

```js
function CreateButtons() {
  var Buttons = document.getElementById("Buttons");
  var Button = null;

  for (let ButtonID = 0; ButtonID < 6; ButtonID++) {
    Button = document.createElement("button");
    Button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Button " + ButtonID));
    Button.onclick = function() {
      ButtonClicked(ButtonID);
    };
    Buttons.appendChild(Button);
  }
}

function ButtonClicked(ClickedID) {
  alert("You clicked button " + ClickedID);
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="CreateButtons();">Create Buttons</button>
<div id="Buttons"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, works fine.